# function SurfaceCreated not getting called when I using handler

Tags: android, handler, surfaceview

I am trying to use `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView` to make a  video player. 
Right now I meet this problem. 
If i put

```
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

in `onCreate()`, everything is ok and the `SurfaceCreated()`can be called succefully. But if i put upper code lines in `handlerMessage()`and use `handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg,1000);` 
in `onCreate()`, then `SurfaceCreated()` can't be called and I do not know why.

Comment: If you don't call `addCallback()` in `onCreate()`, the creation message could arrive before the callback is added.

Comment: @fadden But when I use `sV.getHolder().addCallback(this);` in another method other than in the `onCreate`, it doesn't work.